# What should I use for this project? Cluster, grid or distributed computing?

Tags: java, cluster-computing, distributed-computing, grid-computing

I have a project where I am taking individual tasks that are independent of each other written in Java and executing the tasks on computers across a LAN to solve the tasks efficiently. If the tasks are thread safe they will be executed as threads, otherwise as new JVMs (determined on the original computer) and the results will be sent back to the original computer to be outputted.

I have googled around the subject but keep getting confused between grid, cluster and distributed computing. In the scenario described above, which of these should I use if any?

It should be noted the computers on the LAN are running Windows 7 meaning whatever solution I do find, it needs to run on Windows (some solutions might be *nix only).

Comment: Running multiple java apps with separated JVM instances sounds not-logical to me. plus go for a stable and os you may count on it, such as RHEL (or its family), beside you need to explain more, depends on what are you trying to do, you may get different solutions

Comment: @user5266804 are you saying Windows is not a stable OS? What evidence do you have to back this assertion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand how it makes you get confused between the three words you mentioned but they cannot be compared with each other, let me explain why;

WIKI:

> **Cluster:** A computer cluster consists of a set of loosely or tightly connected computers that work together so that, in many respects, they can be viewed as a single system
>
> **Grid:** Grid computing is the collection of computer resources from multiple locations to reach a common goal.
>
> **Distributed Computing:** Distributed computing is a field of computer science that studies distributed systems. A distributed system is a software system in which components located on networked computers communicate and coordinate their actions by passing messages.

1. So basically Clusters is (at a network or software layer) many computers acting as one.
2. Grid(computation) uses a cluster to perform a task.
3. Distributed computing is one way to perform tasks.

Now what you need is either to use Hadoop or Apache Spark for such tasks or use any in-memory DataGrid for such a purpose but it might be an overkill unless you can tell what exactly are you doing.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown! Just to clarify, in my situation of wanting to execute a number of java tasks from one machine and for those tasks to get executed across a network of machines I could either use a local Cluster, where the system can viewed as a whole and the tasks can execute and run on the system, or a distributed system where the tasks are sent off to individual machines, right? Also I've noticed a lot (if not all) of the Apache projects are only *unix based, do you know of anything similar that runs on Windows (it could even be a Java framework or suchlike)?

Comment: @TomWilkins What are those tasks ? Are they computation extensive or is the data too much. Why do you need to split them ?

Comment: @TomWilkins There are projects on windows but it all depends what type of tasks are you going to run.

Comment: The tasks are Java computations that run independently of each other, some are thread safe, some aren't (they will run in their own JVM). I could look at creating my own schedular, but that would require a lot of complex work on my part, hence me looking for an existing solution (this question was to nail down which solutions to look at).

Comment: How big is your cluster? I might have an answer but i want to understand the requirement first :)

Comment: Im not 100% sure but I think there are around 70 machines that could potentially be used. But obviously I would start of with 2 machines and scale up during development.

Comment: Have you heard of MapReduce ? Best option to do that would either be Hadoop / Apache Spark (Depending on the exact usage) or use an In-Memory Data Grid (which incorporates MapReduce as well)

Comment: @TomWilkins Can you please accept the answer then ? :)